# MacOS Eclipse IDE running applications with older Java version

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm following a Java's Swing course and I'm trying a simple application.

```
package gui_01;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class SimpleEx extends JFrame{

    public SimpleEx( ) {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            var ex = new SimpleEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

but I get this error when trying to run the application:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: gui_01/SimpleEx has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I have the following configurations for the project:

[image: JAVA Building PATH config]

[image: JAVA Compiler settings]

And if I run the command `java -version` from the terminal I get the following result:
[image: Java version got from the Terminal command Java -version]

What can I do to solve it? I'm using :

- Mac: High Sierra
- Eclipse: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Comment: The entry for your program in the 'Run > Run Configuration' dialog configures what is used when you run your code.

Comment: Can you show us the Java runtimes on Eclipse?

Comment: @greg-449 you were right. In the 'Run > Run Configurations ' I managed to chose the right JRE version and now it works like a charm. Thanks both ;) How to I set this to closed?

Answer (score 0):

As @greg-449 suggested going to 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog I managed to select the proper JRE version I want to use.  I post some images just in case the solution helps others.

Lots of thanks ;)

[image: Run->Run Configurations Dialog]

[image: Go to TAB JRE and there you can select the Running Environment]